# Rest service Java, error using jersey dependency

Tags: eclipse, apache, rest, tomcat, jersey

I getting started with Java and rest services, i created a rest service with GET method, this method return a UserVO with his properties, im set properties values with random values using setMethods and return object but this not work mapping object to json of jersey. I using tomcat 6, JDK 1.8.0_121 and eclipse and show this error:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse write
GRAVE: A message body writer for Java class Autoconsulta.ValueObject.UsuarioVO, and Java type class Autoconsulta.ValueObject.UsuarioVO, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
```

VO

```
public class UsuarioVO {

    private String rut;
    private boolean isValid;

    public String getRut() {
        return rut;
    }
    public void setRut(String rut) {
        this.rut = rut;
    }
    public boolean isValid() {
        return isValid;
    }
    public void setValid(boolean isValid) {
        this.isValid = isValid;
    }

}
```

my ret service:

```
@GET
@Path("/getUser")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public UsuarioVO getUsuario() {

    UsuarioVO u = new UsuarioVO();
    u.setRut("123444");
    u.setValid(true);

    return u;
}
```

web xml

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>Servicio_Rest</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>Autoconsulta.ws.rest.service</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Servicio_Rest</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

pom xml

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can you add some details about the error log, i can't seem to see the problem

Comment: If you have the IDE/technology choice, I would recommend working with intellij idea, it's a powerful IDE, and for the restful webservice maybe you can consider working with spring boot rest services, it's well documented and easy to configure, however the choice's yours.

Comment: I think the problem is within your setMethod, because the code you posted seems all fine, however maybe the values generated aren't compatible with what the application consumes, you can post the rest of the code so that we may have a better understanding

Comment: Rest class code:  https://paste2.org/n5H9EnUa AND error log message: https://paste2.org/AgN4IpIn

Comment: From what I see, you need to annotate the UserVO for Jackson. Here are some examples: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations